# Invoke static method dynamically without using reflection

Tags: java, generics, java-10

Say I have something like so:

```
public class Entity<T> {

  public Class<T> model;

  public Entity(Class<T> m){
    this.model = m;
  }

}
```

so we use it like:

```
var ent = new Entity<String>(String.class);
```

but I can't call:

```
ent.model.format()
```

or

```
ent.model.join()
```

etc. None of the static methods are available in this case. Is there a way to call these static methods without using reflection?

Comment: are you sure it shouldn't be `T model`?

Comment: No, but method handles are preety fast.

Comment: Nah it's `Class<T>` not `T`, look at the assignment in the constructor

Comment: Why do you want to do this though? If you know the type at compile time, you could just call a static method normally with `String.join`. If you don't know the type at compile time, the compiler wouldn't know if `T` has a member called `join` at runtime anyway.

Comment: In this case I am passing a Class<?> around instead of an instance around. I would like to call the static methods on the Class<?>, but I can't look them up without reflection, seems like

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you want to bind the type to the attribute in your `Entity` class, for which you can ideally follow the approach as :

```
class Entity<T> {
    public T model;
    public Entity(T m) {
        this.model = m;
    }
}
```

which can then be instantiated as :

```
var ent = new Entity<>(""); // T is inferred based on the attribute type in the c'tor call
// or also  explicitly specified as
var ent = new Entity<String>(""); //redundant though
```

and then use it further as :

```
ent.model.format(""); // in this example 'model' is a 'String' with empty value ""
```

Comment: yeah, I suppose format is being called like `(new String()).format` not the static method `String.format()`...right?

Comment: In the example shared (and as per the code in question), yes. Though a better way would certainly have been `String.format` for that.

Comment: yeah I upvoted, but I don't think this is an affirmative answer to the OP. OP wants to pass in `String.class` not `"a string"` into the constructor.

Comment: @rakim You shall try to explain better in the question then why you want to do that.

Comment: @rakim it would be possible to rewrite the code to work with a `String.class` instead of a `String`; in fact, it’s even possible to rewrite it in a way that you don’t need to pass an argument to the constructor at all. The remaining question still is, why? The `Entity` is entirely irrelevant to what you’re doing, only the compile-time type of the variable matters.  E.g., you could also write `String s = null;  s.format("");` or `Optional<String> o = Optional.empty(); o.orElse(null).format("…");`. If it is about hiding the variable’s type, using `var o = Optional.<String>empty();` would do.